# How to list all Symfony route names with controller class path?

Tags: symfony

I know there is `php app/console debug:router --show-controllers` but it only show Controller::Action. Is it possible to list route names with controller class path ?
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need it from the command line? Since in your screenshot you can see it there.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. If You brave go find controller `sylius.controller.product:indexAction` in some of these bundles https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/src/Sylius/Bundle.

Comment: So isn't enougt to go to product page and see what controller is called in debug bar?

Comment: It isn't enougt. What if `sylius.controller.product:indexAction` is rendered inside twig? My question is more general, I know where `sylius.controller.product:indexAction` point to, but I'm curious if there is smarter way of  finding class path than hunting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no really smart method to see all classes associated to controllers.

Profiler is listening [FilterControllerEvent](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html) to find out a class, and it must be application to be run to fire this event.

But. Controllers you see after running `php app/console debug:router --show-controllers` has two formats: either something like `VendorNameBundle:Task:get` (and in this case it's obvious where to find controller, in `VendorBundle/Controllers/TaskController`) or it's, like in your case, is service's name. And in this case you can find a class by running

```
 php app/console debug:container | grep sylius.controller.product
```